# Storing an array in another array C

Tags: c, arrays, string

In my program, I am currently trying to store a string from an array into another array so I can then have that saved to output later.

```
if(score1 == 3)
            {
                printf("\n\n%s adavances to the next round!",names[i]);
                strncpy(winner[i], names[i], 10);
                printf("\n\nPress Enter to Continue");
                getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
```

That is currently how I am trying to store the array

```
for(p = 0; p > 8; p++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c > 8; c++)
        {
            printf("%c",winner[p][c]);
        }

    }
```

And that is how i am currently trying to output the array, but when i get to the screen with the output nothing is happening.

Comment: What do you mean, "store?"  you are printing the value.??

Comment: Which is the "other" array?

Comment: The reason am I storing it because I am making another function that will be able to print the results from each round (this round being the first)

Comment: Winner is the other array, names[i] is the array i want copied

Answer (score 1):

First off, neither of the loops will run even once :

```
for(p = 0; p > 8; p++)
```

or

```
for(c = 0; c > 8; c++)
```

as **p** & **c** is never greater than **8**

That's one observation. To help you out, we might need additional info like how is the array declared, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry I was a bit ignorance, just started learning.

Comment: For your earlier comment, easiest way is to use `printf("\n");` outside the inner loop